# storing values in sqlite database

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

This is stored database function which stored value in database.but values is not stored in database.Is any fault in code. no error occur.

i want to store values in database.

```
function storefunction() {

  var fname= document.querySelector('#fname').value;//get value from text field
  var ema= document.querySelector('#email1').value;
  var pwd= document.querySelector('#pwd').value;
  var pwd1= document.querySelector('#pwd1').value;
  var mob= document.querySelector('#mob').value;
  var dat= document.querySelector('#outputWindow1').value; 
  var id=5;
  var gen="Male";

        //open the database
 var db=openDatabase('mydb','1.0','test','2*1024*1024'); 
       //insert values in database.
 db.transaction(function (tt){
 tt.executeSql('CREATE TABLE LOG(id,name,email,passwd,date,gender,mobile)');
 tt.executeSql("INSERT INTO LOG (id,name,email,passwd,date,gender,mobile) VALUES ('"+id+"', "+fname+", '"+ema+"', '"+pwd+"', '"+dat+"', '"+gen+"','"+mob+"')");  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you aren't quoting the fname parameter.

```
tt.executeSql("INSERT INTO LOG (id,name,email,passwd,date,gender,mobile) VALUES     ('"+id+"', "+fname+", '"+ema+"', '"+pwd+"', '"+dat+"', '"+gen+"','"+mob+"')");  });
```

}

Should read

```
tt.executeSql("INSERT INTO LOG (id,name,email,passwd,date,gender,mobile) VALUES ('"+id+"', '"+fname+"', '"+ema+"', '"+pwd+"', '"+dat+"', '"+gen+"','"+mob+"')");  });
```

}